# How to Customize ActionBar Title in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-titlebar

I have the following code:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), myAccount);

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// ADD TABS
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
            .setTabListener(this));
}
```

And this is the result of the above code:

[image: Android actionbar title]

What i would like to do is to have my title to be placed above my tabs instead of the other way around as seen in the picture. How do i do this?

*** EDIT 1 ***

I can achieve this with the following code (not using custom layout)

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), myAccount);

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

// ADD TABS
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
            .setTabListener(this));
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Without using custom layout]

I am trying to achieve this but **using** custom layout

Answer (score 0):

```
private String[] tabs = { "English", "Tamil", "Hindi" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
```

They passing string array into tabs, like here tamil, english, hindi.
Change that to watever you want.

Comment: Umm, thanks for answering but i what i would like to do is to swap the position of tabs with my title in the ActionBar (title on top of my tabs).

Comment: Action bar means that is always on top position, wat you asking. swaping action bars to below is not possible dude.

Comment: Thumbqoo is the app name dude, below that action bar is there.
can't get u. Tell clearly.